# Istio service to service communication

Tags: devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, istio, servicemesh

I am new to Istio and I am trying to communicate 2 spring boot applications with Istio: component with requirement.

1. I have installed Istio 1.13.2 on a GKE cluster with the demo profile:

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo -y
```

2. I have automatically injected the sidecar proxy to the default namespace with:

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
```

3. I have defined istio ingress gateway as entry point and a virtual service that points to the component service.

```
 apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http      
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /component
    route:
    - destination:
        host: component
        port:
          number: 8080
---
```

component app only has an enpoint: **/component** that returns a string,  So far everything works fine.

The flow is as follows

my-gateway----->component

My question is how I can communicate component with requirement directly without going through istio-ingress-gateway.

my-gateway----->component ---->requirement

Is it possible?

**Note:** I have tried adding requirements in the virtual service but it seems to go through the istio-ingress-gateway and not directly from component to requirement.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http      
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /component
    route:
    - destination:
        host: component
        port:
          number: 8080
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /requirement
    route:
    - destination:
        host: requirement
        port:
          number: 8080
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure why istio ingress controller coming inbetween for you.

You should checkout this nice simple example : https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/#deploying-the-application

In istio example, you can see **review** service sending the request to **rating** service.

So for connection or service to service communication, you can use the just **service name**.

So if you check the review service source you will get an idea of how services calling other services.

**Java example :**

https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/bookinfo/src/reviews/reviews-application/src/main/java/application/rest/LibertyRestEndpoint.java#L42

**Python example :**

https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/bookinfo/src/productpage/productpage.py#L61

So for you end flow will be something like

```
istio-ingress-gateway----->service-1----->service-2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!, I have reviewed the example again, I had not paid attention to the code of each application, I thought that Istio was in charge of the communication service-a ----> service-b, now I have seen that in the endpoints of each application the calls to each service are made.